# Xcode showing only assembly

Tags: xcode, macos

In my case, there are multiple files in my program. I am compiling my project from makefile and Xcode is only used for debugging. For few particular files, Xcode is **not showing the source code while debugging** but **assembly code**.

I am not able to understand why this is showing assembly code for few files. All the files are being compiled using same option.

All the files are of .cpp extension. These files are of .mm extension (Objective-C++).

Even I am not able to locate source code (as I do in Visual studio to locate source file for debugging).

How to solve this problem?

Comment: How can you compile `.cpp` and `.mm` using the same compiler options?

Comment: Language is detected by file extension, not by compiler option.

Comment: But don't you want to turn ARC on or off?